# Division by countable infinities of comparable magnitudes

Tags: set-theory, divisibility

Suppose we have a countably infinite set, like $\mathbb{N}$ where $|\mathbb{N}| = \infty$.

Does it make sense to say that $|\mathbb{N}|/|\mathbb{N}| = 1$?

How about something like this? Construct a set $A = \{i/2: i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then would it make sense to say that $|A| = 2 |\mathbb{N}|$ and therefore, $|A|/|\mathbb{N}| = 2$?

Comment: No, neither of those "make sense".

Comment: To expand on @GEdgar 's comment, there is a sensible notion of multiplication of cardinal numbers (the standard name for the kinds of infinite numbers you are talking about). On the other hand given cardinal numbers $a$ and $b$, it is often the case that there is no **unique** cardinal number $q$ with $aq=b$. This is what it would take to have a sensible notion of division of cardinal numbers. In particular, in your example $|{\Bbb N}| = |A| = 2\,|{\Bbb N}|$.